# php multiple variable query

Tags: php, mysql

like now i have this php query:

```
$query = "SELECT listing_id, order_expires FROM #__jreviews_paid_orders 
WHERE order_id=".$orderid;
```

i would like to add the following condition - -> order_never_expires != 1

So i tried

```
SELECT listing_id, order_expires FROM #__jreviews_paid_orders 
WHERE order_never_expires != '1' && order_id=".$orderid;
```

and also:

```
SELECT listing_id, order_expires FROM #__jreviews_paid_orders 
WHERE order_id=".$orderid && order_never_expires != '1';
```

but it doesn't work...idea?

Many thanks for your suggestions

Comment: What's all this && business? Use AND in MySql!

Comment: sorry i am not a dev and i have no idea i am just trying to change an existing query, can u help me ?

Comment: if you are not dev.... then maybe you should read manual first? =\ really...

Comment: @Arth Actually `&&` works perfectly well in MySQL. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/expressions.html

Comment: @Mark, I stand corrected, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query.

```
SELECT listing_id, order_expires FROM #__jreviews_paid_orders 
WHERE order_id=".$orderid.” AND order_never_expires != '1';
```

You need to surround the variable with double quotes.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow - if you indent a line by four spaces, it will be formatted as code. Try it out using the "edit" link at the bottom of your post.

Comment: i got the following error: Error: 1054 - Unknown column '176”' in 'where clause' SQL=SELECT listing_id, order_expires FROM up_jreviews_paid_orders WHERE order_id=176”

Comment: @Claudio Are you sure you're using the quotes properly? ".$orderid." **Notice the dots**